# JPA mappedBy reference an unknown target entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am writing a simple inventory database that contains tables for products, orders and customers. The database definition can be found here:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.customers
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('customers_id_seq'::regclass),
    title character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    first_name character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    middle_names character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    last_name character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    email character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    phone_number character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT customers_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE public.products
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('products_id_seq'::regclass),
    name character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    sku integer NOT NULL,
    inventory_on_hand integer NOT NULL,
    reorder_threshold integer NOT NULL,
    price numeric(5,2),
    inventory_to_be_shipped integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT products_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE public.order_items
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('order_items_id_seq'::regclass),
    product_id integer NOT NULL,
    order_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT order_items_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT order_items_order_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (order_id)
        REFERENCES public.orders (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT order_items_product_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
        REFERENCES public.products (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

CREATE TABLE public.orders
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('orders_id_seq'::regclass),
    customer_id integer,
    order_date date NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    arrival_date date,
    CONSTRAINT orders_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT orders_customer_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)
        REFERENCES public.customers (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

I am trying to implement a Spring Security Resource server to perform CRUD operations on the database. I have implemented entity classes for each table in the database but when try to start the server I get a

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: edu.finalyearproject.imsresourceserver.models.Order.customers in edu.finalyearproject.imsresourceserver.models.Customer.orders
```

My entity and repository classes can be found below:

Product.java:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
@Data
public class Product
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer sku;
    private Float price;
    private Integer inventory_on_hand;
    private Integer reorder_threshold;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "order_items",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    )
    private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Customer.java

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
@Data
public class Customer
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private String first_name;
    private String middle_names;
    private String last_name;
    private String email;
    private String phone_number;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Order> orders;
}
```

Order.java

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@Data
public class Order
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id", nullable=false)
    private Customer customer;

    private Date order_date;

    private Date arrival_date;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "orders", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I know the problem is related to the relationships between the entities, but I haven't been able to find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try to correct this:

```java
@Entity
public class Customer
{
    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "orders", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Order> orders;
}
```

to this:

```java
@Entity
public class Customer
{
    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Order> orders;
}
```

See additional explanation in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional).

And you should correct also your `Product`-`Order` `@ManyToMany` association. Only one side of this association should use `@JoinTable` other side should use `mappedBy` property of the `@ManyToMany` annotation. Something like this:

```java
@Entity
public class Product
{
    // ...

    @ManyToMany(
       cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE},
       fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "order_items",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    )
    private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
public class Order
{
    // ...

    @ManyToMany(
       mappedBy = "orders",
       cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE},
       fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>();
}
```

As it is stated in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many-unidirectional):

> For `@ManyToMany` associations, the `REMOVE` entity state transition doesn’t make sense to be cascaded because it will propagate beyond the link table. Since the other side might be referenced by other entities on the parent-side, the automatic removal might end up in a `ConstraintViolationException`.

Also as this is explained in [this section of the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-direct-vs-query):

> If you forget to `JOIN FETCH` all `EAGER` associations, Hibernate is going to issue a secondary select for each and every one of those which, in turn, can lead to N+1 query issues.
>
> *For this reason, you should prefer LAZY associations.*

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment! I've ammended my entity classes as you suggested, but I'm still getting ```mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: edu.finalyearproject.imsresourceserver.models.Order.customer in edu.finalyearproject.imsresourceserver.models.Customer.orders```
I've updated the code snippets to show the changes

Comment: It looks like you use `mappedBy = "customers"`, *but you should use `mappedBy = "customer"`*.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply @SternK, I am using mappedBy = "customer" but I'm still getting the same exception, I'm wondering if I might need a join annotation for the customer in Order.java?
When I include 
```@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id", nullable=false)
    private Customer customer;```
in Order.java I get a ```PropertyReferenceException: No property first found for type Customer!```

Comment: You exception says: *mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: edu.finalyearproject.imsresourceserver.models.Order.customers* that definitely indicate that you use `mappedBy = "customers"` in `edu.finalyearproject.imsresourceserver.models.Customer.orders` please recheck it. Please provide actual exception stack trace.

Comment: ok you were 100% correct, your solution worked as you stated, where I went wrong was I removed the customer attribute that joined the columns in Order.java, since you didnt include it in your solution I mistakenly assumed it needed to be removed. The second exception I mentioned in my next comment was a separate issue caused by my CustomerRepository having a method in it that was incorrect. Thanks for all the help!